# Web socket giving TLS short read error

Tags: websocket

I have a websocket which is connecting to server. But suddenly it started giving error as 
"(1006) TLS short read"
. What are most common or possible reasons when server disconnects you with this error?

Comment: It could be because of load one socket is causing to server. If I create multiple sockets and divide my requests to server, it is not giving this problem anymore.